# How to add div id in an Abstractcell created using uiBinder and UiRenderer

Tags: gwt, uibinder, celllist

Im creating a cellList and using UiBinder for the abstractCell. I want to add div ids to the elements of the cell. How can I achieve that.

Comment: What's wrong with `<div id="123">...</div>`?

Comment: Can you give the uibinder xml and the implementation of your CustomAbstractCell?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Andrei, if I hard code the ids then all the cells have the same id.

Comment: Pintouch, Im actually trying to achieve this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003255/how-to-change-the-text-in-an-abstractcell-created-using-uibinder

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ids that you want in your UiBinder. They will be the same for all cells, but you can easily find the element that you need by calling `getElement` on your cell and iterating through its children nodes, or by using `getInnerHtml` and `indexOf`.